# neo4j graphql with multiple users

Tags: node.js, neo4j, graphql, rbac

We started using [@neo4j/graphql](https://%20https://www.npmjs.com/package/@neo4j/graphql) to have a graphql over our neo4j graph db.

The only problem is that according to the [getting started](https://neo4j.com/docs/graphql-manual/current/getting-started/#_create_an_instance_of_neo4jgraphql) example it is only possible to init the Apollo Server with a single user (driver).

```
const driver = neo4j.driver(
    "bolt://localhost:7687",
    neo4j.auth.basic("neo4j", "password")
);

const neoSchema = new Neo4jGraphQL({ typeDefs, driver });
```

This causes an issue with our RBAC approach as we try to create a user per tenant and deny cross-reads.

Is there a way to use multiple drivers (per user) so that we can map each request to a different user?

Comment: I don't exactly your use case but in Neo4j ver 4+, they added more features like multi databases, different user security and roles. You can explore it and see if it suits your need.

Comment: @jose_bacoy we are already switching to users with different permissions, we just want to connect the graphql-neo4j server to use different neo4j user in each request

Answer (score 1):

I think I found an answer to my question...

Instead of supplying a driver (user) for the server initialization, we can use a [driver in context approach](https://neo4j.com/docs/graphql-manual/current/driver-configuration/#_driver_in_context)

Which will look something like this

```
neoSchema.getSchema().then((schema) => {
    const server = new ApolloServer({
        schema,
        context: ({ req }) => ({ req, some-function-to-extract-driver-from-req }),
    });
});
```